# How can I solv problem with WEB Images API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have repository:

```
public interface IImageRepository
{
    Task<string> UploadAsync(IFormFile file);
}
```

When im creating Cloudinary configuration :

```
    public class CloudinaryImageRepository : IImageRepository
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly Account account;
        public CloudinaryImageRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
            account = new Account(
                configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary")["CloudName"],
                configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary")["ApiKey"],
                configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary")["ApiSecret"]
                );
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<string> UploadAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var client = new Cloudinary(account);
            var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, file.OpenReadStream()),
                DisplayName = file.FileName
            };
            var uploadResult = await client.UploadAsync(uploadParams);

            if (uploadResult != null && uploadResult.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) 
            {
                return uploadResult.SecureUri.ToString();
            }
            // return null;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and check if status OK :

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            //Call a repository
            var imageURL = await imageRepository.UploadAsync(file);

            if (imageURL == null)
            {
                return Problem("Upload unsuccessfull", null, (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
            return new JsonResult(new { link = imageURL });
        }
```

I also have template with JS :

```
        const featuredUploadElement = document.getElementById('featuredImageUpload')
            .addEventListener('change', uploadFeaturedImage);
        
        async function uploadFeaturedImage(e) {
           ** console.log(e.target.files[0]);**

            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', e.target.files[0]);

            await fetch('/api/images', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Aceept': '*/*',
                },
                body: data
            }).then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => **console.log(result)**);
        }
```

and this is the result :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVS5f.png)

I dont understand what i did wrong? How to find mistake? and Why is it give me back error when i upload file?

web images api give error 500 instead json.

Comment: You are using the cloud service to upload the image, to check why this happened, I suggest you could use VS debug mode to debug the application to see which codes return the 500 error.

Comment: I suppose check the correct names of the api controller and action methods you are using. Try with `fetch('/api/images/upload')` in your Js file.